# What is more probable; one 50 percent chance, or ten 5 percent chances?

Tags: probability

What is more probable; a single 50% chance at success, or ten 5% chances at success?

If the former, how many additional 5% chances are required in order for it to be as likely to succeed using multiple 5% chances?

Comment: This is a wrong place to ask this. However, bet on the single one. The probability for the other one is `1-(1-0.05)^10`, which is about `0.4`.

Comment: @george2079 yes it is; please transfer. The names and symbols of the two subsites are very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chance of at least no success in ten tries with probability $p$ is $(1-p)^{10}$ because you have to fail every time. The chance of at least one success is then $1-(1-p)^{10}$.  Substituting in $p=0.05$ gives about $0.4013$.  Your expectation is one half success, but there is a chance of more than one so the chance of at least one has to be lower.  To find how many tries you need, increase the exponent $10$ until you get more than $1/2$